# Склонение фамилии Драга

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняется ли фамилия Драга?

Answer (score 1):

Да, фамилия Драга **склоняется**.   Все фамилии с неударным А на конце склоняются независимо от происхождения. Склонение фамилий подчиняется правилам грамматики русского языка.

Comment: А вы уверены, что здесь ударение не на последний слог? Впрочем. все равно склоняется, если только не французская.